# How to make a linq query wrapper function?

Tags: linq, iqueryable

I have come accross this code on SO and I am trying to convert it to VB.net however I cannot find type 'Result'

```
    public Result QueryWithRetry(IQueryable query)
{
      RetryPolicy retry = new RetryPolicy<MyRetryStrategy>(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); 
     (() => 
     { 
       return retry.ExecuteAction(query);
     }
}
```

What is 'Result' and what namespace do I need to import to access that? I can't find it anywhere!

Comment: I bet it is a generic type and that method should have been `QueryWithRetry (Of Result)(IQueryable (Of Result) query)`.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't yet got it working though due to a different issue. errpr: return retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(query) expression does not produce a value